# Overwrite/disable user stylesheet in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

On chrome (Version 39.0.2171.71 m) I have an issue with all (bootstrap-based) modals.

I've found the problem, but need help fixing it:

The hide class of the modal is being overridden by the *user stylesheet*:

```
/* user stylesheet */ 
.hide {                               
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

(If, for example, I go to [strato.nl](https://www.strato.nl/), and click on the play button (in the middle of the page) for the commercial, I do see the backdrop, but the modal itself doesn't show.)

**Edit**

Let me clarify: I am not building a website, I just have trouble with viewing some sites where they have a *hide* class.

Like in a bootstrap modal with `class="modal hide fade in"`, here it should display the modal (because it is faded in), but chrome's *user stylesheet* actually overwrites the CSS of bootstrap's *hide* class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046738/how-to-disable-css-in-browser-for-testing-purposes ?

Comment: I think he search a method to make it programatically... I don't think it exist. :S

Comment: @jbutler483 I do not wish to disable _all_ CSS, I just want to prevent chrome from overwriting the _hide_ class from the _user stylesheet_

Comment: @Sanjii, I would recommend reading [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4873902/3436942)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around alot, I found out that the issue is an extension which defined:

```
.hide {
   position: absolute !important;
   top: -9999px !important;
   left: -9999px !important;
}
```

By editing the stylesheet of that extension (or removing the extension completely) this issue is fixed.

So basically I dislike the way how chrome displays this in de styles-sidebar of the developer tools, it showed it as `user stylesheet` instead of pointing to the stylesheet of the extension.

Thanks for the answers anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

In the post that jbutler483 showed you, you have this code:

```
var el=document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++){
      if(el[i].getAttribute("type")=="text/css")
             el[i].parentNode.removeChild(el[i]);
};
```

Try it, maybe works.

Comment: This removes all CSS from the page and I want to prevent the _user stylesheet_ from overwriting the _hide_ class

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to over-riding a subsequent stylesheet.

The first is the beloved `!important`:

```
/* your stylesheet */ 
.hide {                               
  position: initial !important;
  top: auto !important;
  left: auto !important;
  /* your other styles here*/
}
```

The alternative is to make your selector more specific than theirs:

```
/* your stylesheet */
div.hide {
  position: initial;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
}
```

Comment: I would like to point out the `!important` tag should only be used **when it must**, not all the time.

Comment: I absolutely agree. I prefer the second method. Even if I only have to prefix the selector with `body` (e.g. `body .hide {`)

Comment: I actually use this method to be able to see the modal if I have to (temporarily adding '!important' manually), but I'm looking for a permament solution.

Answer (score 0):

From your clarification:

1. Open your developer settings (right click) -> inspect element
2. Go down the right hand side (presumably that's where you saw the css)
3. Un-check the css you **don't** want to display

For more information, [see here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles)
[image]

To permanently remove a full **element**, read [this article](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/18/remove-element-website-css-adblock/)