# Best practices for styling an element that can be positioned anywhere in a page

Tags: css, design-patterns, coding-style

I wanted to know if there were a best practice for styling any element that in turn could be placed anywhere in a page and retain its margin.
For example: 
An `<h1>` tag with a ruleset of `margin-bottom: 2rem;` and a `<p>` tag with a ruleset of `margin-top: 2rem`. 
Now these elements can be used anywhere within a webpage. But we the `<h1>` is placed before the `<p>` tag we will be encountered with a spacing of `4rem`, now the behavior that I'd like to have is to maintain the space of one or the other. As a reminder this is a small example, a web page may contain all sorts of html elements as well as buttons and other components. To create a ruleset for each instance and combination is super time consuming and cumbersome, is there a better way?

Comment: If you have the time, this [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NDyopLKE1w) by Nicole Sullivan exemplifies the process of creating a library of web components, which is kind of what you're asking here.

Comment: That was a great talk. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

if you know [margin collepsing](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/) so its help you understand that margin remaining between `<h1>` and `p` is only `2rem` not `4rem` and here a [stackoverflow answerlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873867/whats-the-best-way-to-override-a-user-agent-css-stylesheet-rule-that-gives-unor) for your question... hope you got help form this

Comment: thank you for sharing those links. Kind of made me go in a rabbit hole of good resources. ✌

Answer (score 0):

Most elements (such as `<h1>` and `<p>`) have in-built default vertical margins. These are the 'generally accepted' guidelines, and you shouldn't explicitly *need* to overwrite them. You *can*, however, and if you want to set your own 'generic' margins that can be used anywhere, the best approach would be to use classes. For example:

```
.margin-top {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Any element with this class (such as `<h1 class="margin-top">`) will have this rule overwrite their default. Naturally, you could apply the rule to `h1` directly,

Yes, you will encounter situations where you have both a top and bottom margin sitting next to one another, but you will need to work out when this sort of behaviour is acceptable, and when it is not. One way to avoid this is to make use of [adjacent sibling combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator):

```
h1 + p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Because the above rule has more [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) than the generic `h1` selector, it will take priority.

Yes, it will be a pain to work out all of the possible combinations that you may encounter, and you will have to write rules for each scenario. But you **can** make use of the class-driven approach above in combination with adjacent sibling combinators to significantly help eliminate this problem:

```
.margin-top {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.margin-bottom + .margin-top {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

This will completely prevent any element with the class `margin-top` from applying its margin **only** if it follows a class with `margin-bottom` set.

Note that many other approaches exist to already, and [one such approach](https://medium.com/5000-things/learning-from-lego-a-step-forward-in-modular-web-design-d8ff953f45a8) makes use of a Lego analogy to suggest simply making use of a `padding` on each element that is equal to half of the gutter:

```
$gutter: 20px;
.element {
  padding: $gutter / 2;
}
```

Which is illustrated in a complete proof-of-concept code example [here](https://codepen.io/moyicat/pen/zKYzLp).

Comment: i appreciate the time and effort you put into providing a couple of options. Im in a process of refactoring my code and have to think about these points more closely. Perhaps play with them a bit and see what fits and makes sense to carry on.