# How do we override a user agent CSS property marked with "!important"?

Tags: css

How do we override a user agent CSS property marked with "!important"?

For example:
input[type="password" i] { -webkit-text-security: disc !important; }

from:
https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/resources/html.css

---

Looking at the following chart from mdn, the above task seems impossible:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#cascading_order

The following posts are related, but they don't provide a direct answer to the above question:

- [What's the best way to override a user agent CSS stylesheet rule that gives unordered-lists a 1em margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873867/whats-the-best-way-to-override-a-user-agent-css-stylesheet-rule-that-gives-unor)
- [How to stop user agent stylesheets from overriding my css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415385/how-to-stop-user-agent-stylesheets-from-overriding-my-css)
- https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/you-cant-override-important-user-agent-css-declarations/

---

Edit #1:

I genuinely don't believe this question is a duplicate of [How to override !important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important)  The other question doesn't deal with "user agent" specifically.  "User Agent" has special overriding requirements, and solutions to [the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178673/how-to-override-important) will not work here.

Please kindly review, thanks!

Comment: Please provide a specific example. In some cases it's just a matter of being more specific.

Comment: As you have already gathered, it is impossible. This is intentional.

Comment: Hi @isherwood, "input::-webkit-input-placeholder { line-height: initial !important; }  from https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/resources/html.css

Comment: Hi @Alohci, I don't have any sources from the official CSSWG (or w3.org) spec though.  If someone can provide the official source here, so I can report back to my manager, that would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The official source is the [CSS Cascading and Inheritance Level 5](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-5/#cascading) specification.

Comment: Thanks, Emma. Please put that information in your question, not down here.

Comment: Hi @Alohci, overriding user-agent "!important" should be possible after the introduction of "@layer" in Chrome v99, according to the MDN tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#inline_styles:~:text=include%20an%20important%20declaration%20in%20a%20prior%20cascade%20layer

Comment: @Emma - Sorry, no. Your `@layer`s are all still in the author origin. They can't override !important declarations in the user-agent origin.

Comment: Hi @Alohci, user CSS can have `@layer` too.

Comment: @Emma - true, but that won't override  !important declarations in the user-agent origin either.

Comment: Hi @Alohci, apparently, I found a way to override !important user-agent origin.  I will be posting the answer once the "duplicate" tag is removed.